# How does everyone else search for an element in the DOM of a live page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, dom, web-applications

I got away with some jQuery run from the console:

`$("*").filter(function(){return this.formsField})[0].formsField`

Search through every item that has "formsField", and then grab "formsField".

Advice for doing this smarter?

Comment: Can you share the HTML/DOM + JS on jsbin?

Comment: What elements have a `formsField` property? It doesn't appear to be standard. If you added it yourself, couldn't you just keep a list of such elements yourself?

Comment: What exactly in the DOM are looking for?  What is `formsField`?  Using `$('*')` is never a good idea.  There's a selector that'll work, show us your HTML, and we can help.

Comment: There's no actual html, it's all generated by a ton of other templates, all of which are included/excluded by various conditions.  That's why I'm just playing with a live DOM.  @Rocket:  why is `$('*')` never a good idea?  I found it return a lot of results that clogged the console, but i affixed a `.length` to the end to keep things cleaner while I was playing around.

Comment: @Conrad.Dean: What elements do you want this to return?  It doesn't matter that the HTML was generated.  Show us this generated HTML.  Also, what is `formsField`?  I'm not really sure why, but I always thought `$('*')` was a bad idea.  I mean why get *EVERY* DOM element, when you don't need to.

Comment: Is it an attribute? Although that would not be valid, `$("[formsField]")` may work.

Comment: @Rocket: You're right-- typically, you don't want to grab every DOM element when you can cleverly "pre-filter" your selection ahead of time, but since I'm debugging some uncommented javascript, I want to make sure that I'm grabbing everything at first just in case.  I'll keep your advice in mind when I need to do something like this in production!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a form field?  I think this may be what you want:

```
document.forms["formId"].formsField;
```

Comment: Most likely a form's field, but I wanted to keep it open to all objects named "formsField" in the live DOM, but +1 for `document.forms['name']`!

Comment: @Conrad.Dean - Thanks! So there might be a random object in your dom that has a property called formField?  If it's definitely an element in your form, the code above will be very, very fast.  Parsing the whole dom like you're doing can potentially be quite slow - are you sure you need to?

Comment: Or with jQuery: `$('input[name="formsField"]', 'form[name="form1"]')`.

Comment: @Rocket - sure - but some people get testy when they see jQuery solutions when the native one is just as good :)

Comment: @AdamRackis: Agreed.  Just figured I'd throw it out there.